# Use $$ in dollar quoted string with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am trying to update a column with jOOQ in a block statement. My Kotlin code looks like this (`newName` and `id` are Kotlin variables):

```kotlin
dslContext.begin(
    ...,
    dslContext.update(MYTABLE).set(MYTABLE.NAME, newName).where(MYTABLE.ID.eq(id))
    ...,
).execute()
```

jOOQ generates SQL like this for PostgreSQL (using jOOQ version 3.18.0):

```sql
do
$$
begin
    ...;
    update "public"."mytable" set "public"."mytable"."name" = '...';
    ...;
end;
$$;
```

which is perfectly ok, unless the new name contains '$$'. I'm getting an 'Unterminated string literal' error, if I'm trying to set the name to something like `foo$$bar`.

I was able to solve this problem, by splitting the new name by `$$` and recreating the original String using `DSL.concat(...)`. It would be easier, if jOOQ would create a dollar quoted string with a tag, e.g. generate something like

```sql
do
$FOO$
begin
    ...;
    update "public"."mytable" set "public"."mytable"."name" = '...';
    ...;
end;
$FOO$;
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jOOQ should handle this better, indeed. I've created a feature request for jOOQ 3.19: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14800. Starting from jOOQ 3.19, you can specify:

```java
settings.setRenderDollarQuotedStringToken("FOO")
```

Prior to jOOQ 3.19, this isn't configurable, but you can patch the generated SQL with an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html), e.g.

```java
class PostgresDoPatchListener implements ExecuteListener {
    @Override
    public void renderEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        ctx.sql(ctx.sql().replaceAll(
            "do\\s+\\$\\$(.*)\\$\\$", 
            "do \\$FOO\\$$1\\$FOO\\$"
        ));
    }
}
```